Free app/website for learning Japanese
I want to learn Japanese using a completely free (iOS) app or website. I’m currently using Duolingo (very low knowledge level right now), but any simple web search will explain why Duolingo is bad at teaching Japanese.
There should be spelling (typing?) exercises, listening exercises, speaking exercises (if only for the app), and exercises in the different writing styles.
Does this exist?

I don't think this app exists

@user366875 Why not?

This is because nobody will invest their time or money to make the app tailored to your learning needs. You'd better research other ways to study.

@user366875 I don’t want someone to make it for me, I just want to know if it exists already.

All I did was to provide the reason why it doesn't exist.

Duolingo already does everything you are asking for AFAIK, with only reason you reject it is "web search will explain why Duolingo is bad at teaching Japanese". I think you should point out in this question what exactly should your application do differently to Duolingo.

You should look into Anki. There is a bit of a learning curve but once you learn how to use it and some complimentary programs you can do all of those things you described with some time investment. Check out pre-made decks on the Anki website, an add-ons called MorphMan, and a program called Subs2SRS.
Good luck!

That's just a flashcard app though. It doesn't actually teach you anything, it's just a review tool.

It's a tool. You can use it for a variety of purposes. Check out sentence decks people already made for convenience. Use MorphMan to sort them so you get more bang for your buck. Use Subs2SRS to generate flashcards from real media you consume, after which you can make listening cards (audio front, text+meaning back), pronunciation cards ( text front+ audio back) etc. If you don't want to learn to use these free tools you gotta pay up and buy some course+tutors. I learned with the method mentioned above exclusively (didn't use pre-made decks except for kanji) and got my N1 in 2 years from 0.

As @Daemons wrote, Anki is just a review tool, not an app for learning Japanese. The availability of shared decks does not change this. People who "learn" Japanese with pre-made decks are putting the cart before the horse. The right way to use a flashcard app as a self-learner is to create cards based on your learning materials. The second-best way is to use decks that were created for the same learning materials. Everything else will be disconnected from what you are learning.

Did you even read my comment? I recommended Subs2SRS to make flashcards out of native content you consume for vocabulary, listening and pronunciation exercises (pre-made decks are good at the start to get you feet wet when you don't know anything). How is this not learning? Saying Anki is just a review tool is like saying a book is just a reading tool, true but incomplete. You watch something, understand the message and the context, then make flashcards to study the vocabulary you don't know and commit them to your long-term memory. Sounds like the process of learning a language, don't it?

I would guide you towards the Learning Japanese Starting Guide from /r/LearnJapanese. It has a comprehensive overview of apps and other online resources, both paid and unpaid.
